# Exponential shadow maps sampling with PCF for sampler2DShadow instead of sampler2D

Tags: opengl, lighting, glsl, shadow

I am trying to make use of free hardware PCF sampling with `sampler2DShadow` and extend it to more samples.

So far I am sampling shadow map (`sampler2D`) in ESM way and extending this to PCF and it works.
So I have no acne (thanks to ESM) and soft result, but I need a lot of PCF samples:

```
float shadowMapSize = 512.0;
float c = 5000.0;
float receiver = lightCoords.z;
float shadow = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_NUM; ++i)
{
    vec2 off = (POISSON_SAMPLES[i])/shadowMapSize;
    float occluder = texture(shadowmap, lightCoords.xy+off).r;
    shadow += exp(c*(occluder-receiver));
}
shadow /= SAMPLE_NUM;

shadow = clamp(shadow, 0.0, 1.0);
```

But I wanted to use `sampler2DShadow` and get 4 PCF tabs for free and extend this to 16 taps for almost free with only 4 poisson samples like that:

```
float shadowMapSize = 512.0;
float c = 5000.0;
float receiver = lightCoords.z;
float shadow = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_NUM; ++i)
{
    vec2 off = (POISSON_SAMPLES[i])/shadowMapSize;
    float occluder = texture(shadowmap, vec3(lightCoords.xy+off, receiver)).r;
    shadow += exp(c*(occluder-receiver));
}
shadow /= SAMPLE_NUM;
shadow = clamp(shadow, 0.0, 1.0);
```

But unfortunately it doesnt work as expected:

[image]

Is there a way to make it work (in ESM way, not traditional due to acne) or due to `sampler2DShadow` specification it is rather impossible? In traditional way it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCF does N shadow tests, where each test returns 1 (in light) or 0 (in shadow), and returns the average of the results. `sampler2DShadow` is a special sampler where PCF is applied to the nearest texels to a sample, based on the depth coordinate provided. So you can't use it with ESM.